# Hydronic boiler sharing 20A circuit

Tags: electrical, boiler

I would like to connect my hydronic boiler to a 20A circuit already loaded by a microwave and a range hood. The label on the boiler says it draws `LESS THAN 12A`.

[image]

Does this run a risk of overloading the circuit?

Comment: Depending on size of microwave would say yes.  Microwave, boiler and range hood together will probably be enough over 20 amps to trip on same circuit.  Less than 12 amps sounds more like max you can use, compared to uses.

Comment: The risk is very high.   "Less than 12 amps" presumably means it might sometimes use up to 12 amps.  A typical microwave uses 8 or 9 amps.  A range hood uses more than zero.  If you have a very small microwave and range hood, there is a small chance you *won't* overload the circuit.   Also, I think your boiler is required to have a dedicated circuit, but I'll let others confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do that.

> NEC 422.12 – Central heating equipment other than fixed electric space-heating equipment shall be supplied by an individual branch
> circuit.

> Exception No. 1:  Auxiliary equipment, such as a pump, valve, humidifier, or electrostatic air cleaner directly associated with the heating equipment, shall be permitted to be connected to the same branch circuit.
>
> Exception No. 2:  Permanently connected air-conditioning equipment
> shall be permitted to be connected to the same branch circuit.

You need a dedicated circuit.

Depending on your LAHJ, you may also not be legally permited to install a boiler, period, unless you are licensed for that trade. Boiler mishaps are expensive in terms of dollars and lives, leading to considerable legislation applying to their installation.

Comment: okay, I have 2 15A circuits running through a JB nearby that I think I can integrate in one (lights and outlets only) and use one for the boiler

Answer (score 1):

I'll stick my neck out here and provide another reason not to do what you want.

The other answers note correctly that your boiler must be on a dedicated circuit, and that 12 + anything is a lot.

But.

Why would a gas boiler use 12A?  Makes no sense.  I propose it doesn't.  The power consumption of a gas hot water boiler is mainly in the circulator, usually about 1 amp, and indicated on the circulator's name plate, not the boiler's.  If there are other accessories like a flue damper, zone valves, etc that are permitted to be on the same circuit, you need to add up their power requirements.

The actual power consumption of the boiler is probably, if it is anything like mine, closer to 0.07 amps and that includes two smart thermostats and the leakage from several 24V transformers.

I believe what is meant by "Input less then 12 Amps" is that the dedicated circuit that this boiler MUST be on, for practical purposes needs to have a 10A breaker on it and not a 15A one.

So if you put it on a shared 20A circuit with a microwave and a range hood, and perhaps a 1 amp circulator, the answer to your question is probably that you will *not* overload the circuit, but you will violate code in two ways: 1) the one indicated in the other answers, and 2) putting the boiler on a 20A breaker when it needs a 10A (or anything less than 12, which means 10) one.

That requirement may also be a good reason (other than compliance) not to use a power cord and plug.  You could then plug it into a 15A or 20A circuit, and fail to protect it internally however it needs to be protected by a 10A breaker.

Comment: `Why would a gas boiler use 12A?` -- exactly, the only power it uses is for the pump to recirc water through the radiators

Comment: The boiler's *usage* does not include the circulator's.  The 12A is something else.  I'm not sure my interpretation of "less than" is correct.  Can you post a picture of the entire nameplate including the make and model?

Comment: @amphibient the whole point of a nameplate is to be an authoritative source for how much current you must provison.  You can't really argue around the nameplate.

Comment: @Harper but what does "less than" mean?  Does it mean it consumes less than 12A?  Or that it needs a breaker less than 12A ?   Or something else?  Unclear to me.  My answer is a bit of a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, would you say 12A is *a small part* of 20A, or would you say it's *most* of 20A?  Anytime you see a math problem like this, convert it into a *money* problem: if we earned $20 on a job, is $12/$8 a fair split?

Anyway you may have fallen into a fallacy of logic.  Being eager to do it this way, you optimistically hope a microwave and range hood draw less than 8A together.  You could find out for sure, but then, you'd have to face facts :)

But aside from that, there are three deal-killers in NEC.

- The microwave uses a cord and plug into a receptacle.  It's in the kitchen.  Kitchen receptacle circuits (like the microwave/hood) can't power anything outside the kitchen area.
- Furnaces must be hard-wired. If a hardwired load uses >50% of the circuit ampacity (12A is 60% of 20A) then *no receptacles can be on that circuit at all*.
- Furnaces require a dedicated circuit regardless (as Ecnerwall covers).

You don't just want a separate circuit. You want a separate panel.

Or to be more precise, you want to see if you can get a sensibly priced *generator interlock* for your main panel.  If you can't, then you want to install a subpanel near it, and install a generator interlock there.

The reason is: power loss is inevitable. With the increasing popularity of generators, and the *ballistically increasing* popularity of non-generator things that act like generators such as electric vehicles with AC sockets, you will probably want to be able to power this furnace (and a few other things) during a power outage.  The easy way to do that is a $40 sub panel (Siemens 12-space; better a $70 24-space) and a $25 generator interlock (Siemens ECSBPK01).  And Square D and Eaton have comparable things.

The sooner you "get going on this" the better.  Nobody is in "we don't have power outages around here" territory anymore.  Not with Seattle and Texas getting freezes, the dry southwest getting transmission line shutdowns during windy wildfire conditions, and solar/wind taking an outsize part of generating capacity *which can no longer be time-shifted using pumped storage, as the dams are out of water*.